# How to install the Django plugin for the Eric IDE?

Tags: python, django, ide, eric-ide

I can't believe I have to ask this, but I have spent almost three hours looking for the answer.  Anyway, I have Eric IDE 4 installed on my linux distro.  I can't seem to download any plugins to the plugins repository.

The only one I really want is the Django plugin so when I start a new project in Eric, the Django option shows.  The plugin repository just shows me an empty folder for .eric4/eric4plugins and there's no follow up as to where I can get the plugins from somewhere else.  Actually, there was a hinting at it on the Eric docs site, but what I ended up getting was the ENTIRE trunk for eric.  And the plugins that came with the trunk are just the bare bones ones that ship with it.  I didn't get the Django one and the documentation on the Eric site is seriously lacking and overly complex.

Anyone know how I can just get the Django snap in?

Comment: If this is for work, I'd just fork out the 100 bucks for PyCharm, but that's just me. (I'm not affiliated with the people making it, just have great mileage with their tools.)

Comment: thanks...  I guess I'll have to do that.

Answer (score 4):

In the `Plugins` dropdown menu click on `Plugin repository...`
Make sure that the repository URL is: `http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/plugins4/repository.xml`  and then click on update.

The Django plugin will show up in the list of available plugins, click on it and then click the download button. That should download the plugin for you.

After that you need to actually install the plugin as well: In the `Plugins dropdown` menu click on `Install plugins`. Then select your newly downloaded Django plugin and install it.

Good luck!

Comment: I installed the Django plugin but for some reason I cannot create a new Django project in Project / New. In the field "Project Type" Django doesn't appear as it should be. In the same time I'm able to create a Dango project from the command line with `django-admin stratproject ...`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to ryuusenshi's good answer you also have to check that the enviroment is correctly set in

```
settings -> preferences -> debugger -> python3
```

and

```
settings -> preferences -> django
```